# Count consecutive number of 1s in each column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with each cell having either a 0 or a 1. I would like a code to go through each column and count the number of ones in each column. If 1s come in the cells of a column consecutively 45 times, that should give me an occurrence of 1 for that column. I would also like to know if this occurrence occurs multiple times in a column. So, the occurrence value could be 0 (if 1s dont come in the column for 45 times consecutively), 1 or more. I tried to code for this but I have no idea how to do so. Thank you for any help.

P.S If 1 comes consecutively for 90 times, that should not give me an occurrence of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x1 <- rleid(x); list(table(x1[x!=0]))})]
```

---

Or another option is `rle` from `base R`

```
lapply(df1, function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[values==1]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 5*20, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: Ur answer works wonderfully. Could you please incorporate a bit which also tells me which row numbers are there for these consecutive occurrences of 1.

Comment: @TheLastWord It is not clear how you want the answer.  If you require the row numbers `lapply(df1, function(x) {i1 <- seq_along(x)*x; x1 <- with(rle(x),  lengths[values==1]); i1[x!=0]})`